# How to create a simple system plugin in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to create a System Plugin in Joomla 2.5. Where to get the sample code for a simple system plugin in Joomla 2.5.4

Please give a sample code of Joomla System Plugin .

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=how+to+create+a+joomla+2.5+plugin

Answer (score 0):

here you can find your documentation and sample codes to create a plugin in joomla 2.5
just follow the instruction in this tutorial:

[J2.5:Creating a Plugin for Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)

Comment: Ok...if you can please give the details about the events in System Plugin. I know the name of the events,But i don't when the events are executing.

Comment: Apart from the official instructions, maybe try finding similar plug-ins to what you want to do in the Joomla Extensions Directory as example. This was the most useful resource to me when I created my first plug-in.